# I can't run any command in Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc

I tried to enter the command `nano ~/.bashrc` in order to include some path into the `.bashrc` file in home directory but I'm not able to run **any** command and I get always the following error:

```
rag@rag-Satellite-C640:~$ nano ~/.bashrc
Command 'nano' is available in the following places
 * /bin/nano
 * /usr/bin/nano
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
nano: command not found
```

Why this is happening with any command that I'm trying?

What I want to do is edit the `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 6):

- Update the `PATH` variable to include `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin`.

```
export $PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin
```

- Open the `/etc/environment` file to save the variable permanently.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/environment
```

- Make sure the `PATH` variable is initialized as follows:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem but  I solved it with the following command run on the terminal.

```
export PATH=${CUDA_INSTALL_PATH}/bin:${PATH}
```

Comment: This only applies to not being able to run CUDA commands, I think the original poster meant not being able to run any commands at all.